# How to do a GET on my localhost node server using curl?

Tags: node.js, linux, rest, express, curl

I am trying to GET a page from my localhost server using the command line on linux.

I have my node's REST endpoint like this:

```
app.get('/autogen',function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.status(200).send("OK");
});
```

And going here on my browser works perfectly:

[image: chrome output]

**However, I can't figure out how to use CURL to do the same GET request via the command line.**

Here is what I have tried:

- `curl -H "Accept: */*" -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`
- `curl --ipv4 -H "Accept: */*" -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`
- `curl -i -H "Accept: */*" -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`
- `curl -H "Accept: text/html" -H "Content-Type: text/html" -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`
- `curl -H "Accept: text/html" -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`
- `curl -H "Accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`
- `curl -I -H "Accept: */*" -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`
- `curl --ipv4 -X GET http://localhost:8084/autogen -v`

**ALL CURL COMMANDS RETURN** Response: HTTP/1.1 **204 No Content**

==================================

## Logs & Info

Here is the **full log of the response message from the CURL commands** above (substituted sections with {}):

```
* About to connect() to proxy {MYCOMPANYPROXY} port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying {MYIP}... connected
* Proxy auth using Basic with user '{MYNAME}'
> GET http://localhost:8084/autogen HTTP/1.1
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic {...}
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8084
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> Accept: text/plain
> Content-Type: text/plain
> 
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 21958
< 
* Excess found in a non pipelined read: excess = 3013 url = /autogen (zero-length body)
* Connection #0 to host {MYCOMPANYPROXY} left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Also here is the **full headers from vising the page via chrome**:

[image: headers from chrome]

Also my **no_proxy** environment variable is set to not be used on **localhost**:

```
echo $no_proxy
localhost,127.0.0.1,*.dom1,*.grp
```

And here's the **versions** of what I'm using:

```
**Express Version:  3.14.0
**Node Version:  v6.5.0
**Curl version: curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Also, side note, my server will tell me when someone goes to that page like

```
GET /autogen 200 10.168 ms - 2
GET /autogen 304 1.617 ms - -
```

But when I use the curl commands I get NOTHING so it must not be resolving or something

Comment: Your chrome is apparently from the headers not using the proxy (should it?) while your curl request definitely is, and the proxy is apparently misbehaving; not only does the server apparently not get an origin request, but 204 with c-length and c-type makes no sense. The env var for curl to skip a configured proxy is **`NO_PROXY` all caps** (and make sure it's an env var not a shell var, i.e. is exported)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 oooh it's the proxy messing me up again! I definitely don't want the proxy to be used. I did `echo $NO_PROXY` but it was the same as `$no_proxy`, however I did create a file `~/.curlrc` that contains `proxy=...`. I removed this file and BAM! It worked!!! Thank you dave!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dave_thompson_085 helped me with this one!

Apparently chrome **was not** using a proxy, and curl **was**, and I do NOT want to use the proxy.

The cause was my curl settings file `~/.curlrc`. It contained something like this:

```
proxy=http://myuser:mypass@myproxy
```

So, **I removed `~/.curlrc`** and BAM! Works now!

Thank you!